# How to select random rows whose column sum meets the condition in Sql server

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to select random rows from a table whose particular column total (sum) should be less than my condition value ?

My table structure is like -

```
id | question | answerInSec
1  | Quest1   | 15
2  | Quest2   | 20
3  | Quest3   | 10
4  | Quest4   | 15
5  | Quest5   | 10
6  | Quest6   | 15
7  | Quest7   | 20
```

I want to get those random questions whose total sum of 'answerInSec' column is less than (nearest total) or equal to 60.

So random combination can be [1,2,3,4] OR [2,3,5,7] OR [4,5,6,7] etc.

I tried as follows but no luck

```
select id,question,answerinsec
from (select Question.*, sum(answerinsec) over (order by id) as CumTicketCount
      from Question 
     ) t 
where cumTicketCount <= 60
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this one help

```
DECLARE @MaxAnswerInSec INT = 60
DECLARE @SumAnswerInSec INT = 0
DECLARE @RadomQuestionTable TABLE(Id INT, Question NVARCHAR(100), AnswerInSec INT)

DECLARE @tempId INT, 
        @tempQuestion NVARCHAR(100), 
        @tempAnswerInSec INT

WHILE @SumAnswerInSec <= @MaxAnswerInSec
BEGIN       
    SELECT TOP(1) @tempId = Id, @tempQuestion = Question, @tempAnswerInSec = AnswerInSec
    FROM Question 
    WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM @RadomQuestionTable) 
    AND AnswerInSec + @SumAnswerInSec <= @MaxAnswerInSec
    ORDER BY NEWID()    

    IF @tempId IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RadomQuestionTable VALUES(@tempId, @tempQuestion, @tempAnswerInSec)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN   
        BREAK
    END

    SELECT @tempId = NULL
    SELECT @SumAnswerInSec = SUM(AnswerInSec) FROM @RadomQuestionTable  
END

SELECT * FROM @RadomQuestionTable
```

Comment: Thanks Edward but in some cases it is failing to fill the actual data, I am getting a total of 55 some times

Comment: @Chaitanya I would say it will be complex to make sure that always return 60. In this case, maybe we can execute more than one times if it return 55.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Try this. This might not be the fastest, but is easier to understand and implement. Moreover this is a SQL-only solution:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t3.id, t4.id FROM Question t1 CROSS JOIN Question t2 
CROSS JOIN Question t3 CROSS JOIN Question t4 
WHERE t2.id > t1.id AND t3.id > t2.id AND t4.id > t3.id
AND t1.answerInSec + t2.answerInSec + t3.answerInSec + t4.answerInSec = 60
```

What this basically does is to create a cross product of your Questions table with itself and then repeats this process two more times, thus creating `N ^ 4` rows where N is the number of rows in your table. It then filters out duplicate rows by only those selecting the permutations where `t1.id < t2.id < t3.id < t4.id`. It then filters remaining rows by looking for the rows where the sum of all score fields is equal to your target value (60).

Note that this result set can become HUGE for even moderately sized tables. For example, a table with just 200 rows will generate a cross product of 200 ^ 4 = 1,600,000,000 rows (though a lot of them will be discarded by the `WHERE` clause). You should have your indexes in place if your table is large.

Also note that this query does not account for the permutations where less than 4 rows may add up to 60. You can easily modify it to do that by including a NULL row in your table (a row whose score field is zero).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT      *
FROM        question
WHERE       answerInSec<50
ORDER BY    CHECKSUM(NEWID())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.